# Какие есть правила хранения данных банковских реквизитов организаций и ИП?

Tags: хранение-данных, данные

Мне необходимо хранить данные о банковских реквизитах ООО и ИП. Данные о самом банке, в котором находится счет я получаю из DaData, номер расчетного счета вводится вручную.
Но необходимо понимать, есть ли какие-то ограничения для хранения номеров счета НЕ физических лиц.
Не могу найти никаких правовых актов, регулирующих это или указаний роскомнадзора и т.д.
Подскажите пожалуйста, может кто-то сталкивался с таким вопросом

Answer (score 0):

Федеральный закон от 08.08.2001 N 129-ФЗ (ред. от 26.11.2019) "О государственной регистрации юридических лиц и индивидуальных предпринимателей"

Статья 6. Предоставление содержащихся в государственных реестрах сведений и документов

1. Содержащиеся в государственных реестрах сведения и документы являются открытыми и общедоступными

Далее там есть ограничения про перс.данные учредителей и про особые предприятия